# Unity Gameobject is far away from the Move Tool

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

why is my Gameobject so far away from the Move Tool as you can see in the Picture down below?

I would like to have it centered at the Gameobject. How can I change this?

[GameObject away from Move Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmsM9.png)

[Screenshot of Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3MAC.jpg)

Comment: Numerous reasons, can you show us your hierchy? (in the top there is a pivot toggle on the top of unity that will try and center the pivot in the middle of all selected gameObjects could be one for example)

Comment: Here is a [Screenshot of Hierachy](https://imgur.com/a/yKEGsyf) @Eddge

Comment: new screenshots used to help answer your question should be added to your original question.  This way future people dont have to search through the comments looking for additional information.  unfortunately imgur is blocked where I am at currently, I will check back later...

Comment: It  looks like the Canvas is selected, not the GameObject

Comment: I have 2 Canvas (Shop and Gamescreen). The Components and their values are indentical. For Gamescreen the Move Tool is centered but not for the Shop.

Answer (score 0):

Check the object in the scene hierarchy and make sure that the transform eg. x,y,z are set to 0.

If your object is a child of another object and they are not at the same position you are probably moving the parent and not the child object itself.

Answer (score 0):

that `Move Tool` is the objects origin, and this might help:

"The easiest way is to create an empty object as a parent object. Then you put the corridor object as a child of the empty object. You can then alter the position of the corridor object so its positioned at the edge.

i found your answer [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/609267/how-to-change-the-origin-of-a-gameobject.html)

note that its not exact, in your case, make an empty object, move it to where you would like your origin or `move tool` THEN add your other object to it as a child. you can then move it with the parents `move tool`(origin) right on top of your box.

Comment: Thanks! I created a empty GameObject now and used all the Components I used from the original one. Than I moved the Childs to the new GameObject and it worked. Thanks!